# Converting 8 bit PNG to 32- bit with alpha

Tags: image, google-play, imagemagick, png

I have an Image: `PNG image data, 403 x 343, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced`. I want to convert this into Google Play Icon size: `32-bit with alpha.`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed it using https://pixlr.com/editor/. Just open and save the image with full quality.

Comment: Not working. It saves it again with 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced. Any other solution? Need to publish app on playstore

Comment: It may work but do I really want flash to access my harddrive?

Answer (score 5):

With imagemagick:
`convert <file> png32:<newfilename>.png`

With Gimp: open, add alpha channel (Layer > Transparency > Add alpha channel), set RGB mode (Image > Mode > RGB) and export as png.

Comment: Worked just fine.

Comment: After doing this with gimp 2.10.30 I see the .png file only has 16 bits per pixel, not 32.

Answer (score 2):

Gimp -> export as -> png -> choose 16bpc RGBA