# Issue with playstore app upgrade while uploading images

Tags: google-play

Am trying to push an APK to the Google Play Store, and am having issues.

When am trying to upload images it is not accepting.

They mentioned like image format should be 24-bit PNG alpha.

How to convert images to this format?

Comment: A google search for "convert images to 24 bit alpha PNG" gives lots of results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting 8 bit PNG to 32- bit with alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462515/converting-8-bit-png-to-32-bit-with-alpha)